# Power Query add multiple empty colums?

Tags: dax, powerquery

I need to add 12 empty columns in Power Query with custom names.
Now I am adding one column at the time and change the name.

Is it possible to do this faster/better?

I tried the first option but get an error.
When I add a column with code

```
= Table.FromColumns(
Table.ToColumns(#"Prev Step") & {{null}, {null}, {null}}, 
Table.ColumnNames(#"Prev Step") & {"Empty1", "Empty2", "Empty3"}
```

)

I get a lot of rows in the three columns.
What am I doing wrong?
[image: Faulty output]

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 2):

How about this for adding three empty columns? Extend to more as needed.

```
= Table.FromColumns(
    Table.ToColumns(#"Prev Step") & {{null}, {null}, {null}}, 
    Table.ColumnNames(#"Prev Step") & {"Empty1", "Empty2", "Empty3"}
  )
```

Comment: Thanks,  I put the code in a custom column but the reference Prev Step gives an error. Should I replace it? But with what?

Comment: With whatever the name of the previous step is. Maybe it's `#"Changed Type"` or `#"Filtered Rows"`. I can't tell without seeing your query.

Answer (score 1):

By generating lists of columns and associated names, you can specify just the number of columns to add, and let the list of nulls and names be generated automatically.
eg:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSkksSVQwVIrVgTKNlGJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//add Multiple Blank Columns
    numCols = 12,
    colNames = List.Generate(
        ()=>[colName = "Blank", idx=0],
            each [idx] < numCols,
            each [colName = "Blank" & Number.ToText([idx]+1), idx = [idx]+1],
            each [colName]
        ),

    addedCols = Table.FromColumns(
                    Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & List.Repeat({{null}},numCols),
                    Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & colNames)
in
    addedCols
```